# positioning entries on a timeline

Tags: javascript, css, math

Hello I have calender/schedule in an app that looks similar to this very basic example,

> | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
>
> ---
>
> Project #1 (Runs from start of Jan to mid March)     ...............
>
> ```
>             Project #2 (Runs from mid march to early september)
>             ..............................
> ```

The dots under the project title illustrate the length of the project, what I am struggling with is giving the entry the correct value of left margin to push the project to the correct start date.

The figures I have available to me are:

1. Number of days the projects run,
2. Number of days between the 01/01/2014 and the first days of the project.
3. Total number of days in the calendar (the calendar runs Jan 2014 - Dec 2019).
4. Width of the container holding the calendar.

I thought it would be something like this:

```
var remainder = number_of_days_in_calendar - this.model.get('num_days_from_year_start');
var decimal = remainder / number_of_days_in_calendar;
var marginLeft = decimal * 100 + "%";
```

But this returns percentages far too close together there is barely any difference between, Jan and August.

I have worked out the project length successful using this sum,

```
var width = (parseInt(this.model.get('run_number_days')) / number_of_days_in_calendar) * 100;
this.$el.width(width + "%");
```

But nothing similar works for positioning the projects.

Comment: Let's say `number_of_days_in_calendar = 365`, `day_when_project_started = 91` and `container = 365px` => `((91 / 365) * 100) * (365px / 365) = margin-left: 24.93%` If would container be, let's say `730px` the final result would be `margin-left: 49.86%;`

Comment: Yes your solution thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the margin based on the total width of the calendar on screen.

```
width = calendar width in pixels * decimal
```

If I understand correctly *decimal* in your calculation is the percentage of days before the project start to the total number of days in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have these values

```
number_of_days_in_calendar = 365
day_when_project_started = 91
container_width = 365px
```

this is how we could calculate the position of left margin

```
((91 / 365) * 100) * (365px / 365) = margin-left: 24.93%
```

If the container is, for instance `730px` wide, according to the formula above, the final result would be `margin-left: 49.86%;`